# Removing Yoast SEO plugin v4.6 and credit

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

i am working on a project to remove a credit from WP plugin because it is showing in source code under header code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a plugin, all the texts or contents are in the plugin folder.
Open all the files in a text edit sodtware like Sublime Text, and press `ctrl+shift+F` to find a string across all the files. You will find a result, then just remove or change it, and upload on your web server.

But don't forget why credits exists, it's many work to create this kind of plugin, and if the credit is not visible on the web page (like in the footer), you should keep it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit files of the plugin, but I think the next update of the plugin will overwrite your changes.

You can also add a `display:none` to the credits, [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

But don't forget, credits are a way to pay and thank the developer for is work ;)

Comment: will you be happy when you knew that someone have removed your credits?